# Bootstrap NavBar Web&Mweb toggle on the right title on the left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate this behavior for my website but I am really struggling with bootstrap, html and css.

The idea is to have:

- Web: A nav bar with menu on the left, brand text on the centered and some social icons on the right.
- Mweb(so when the screen is small). Brand text on the left, toggle on the right that opens full screen.

Can anyone help me out?

[image: web view]
[image: mobile view]